# Hive SQL - spilit string fixed length

Tags: hive

i have input like this: However the string is dynamic so may smaller in length or bigger. So every 3 chars need to insert the PIPE delimiter.

```
1234567890
```

and I need output

```
123|456|789|0
```

How can I do that in HQL using split function or regular_replace function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: And just to be clear: you simply want to have the | char after every 3 chars?

Comment: Yes, However the string is dynamic , so have to loop through every 3 chars in a big string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this crude of of doing it by using CONCAT and SUBSTR functions assuming you know the position to add pipe.

```
select CONCAT(SUBSTR(COL_USERCODE,1,3),'|',SUBSTR(COL_USERCODE,4,6)) from USER_DETAILS;
```

Let me know if this is helpful

Cheers

~YSW

Comment: String is dynamic like 123458888999222 so can’t use static positions, I did try with regular replace but it won’t work for hive.yes for every 3 chars should see | delimiter.

Comment: @hguru did you get a chance to look at my above answer of using Hive UDF

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use Hive UDF to achieve this, use this sample java code which is applicable for your case.

```
package com.ysw.hiveudf;
 import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
 import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
 public class StringParser extends UDF {
    public Text evaluate(String userString) {
            Text result = new Text();
            String token ="|";
            int tokenPosition = 3;
            int startPosition = 0;
            int endPosition = tokenPosition;
            String parsedAndUpdatedString="";
            if(userString.length() <= tokenPosition) {
                result.set(StringUtils.strip(userString));
                return result;
            }else {
                for(int i=0;i<userString.length() && startPosition <=userString.length() ;i++) {
                    if(endPosition < userString.length()) {
                        parsedAndUpdatedString = parsedAndUpdatedString+userString.substring(startPosition, endPosition)+"|";
                    }else { 
                        parsedAndUpdatedString = parsedAndUpdatedString+userString.substring(startPosition)+"|";
                    }   
                    startPosition = endPosition;
                    endPosition = startPosition+ tokenPosition;
                }
            }
            result.set(StringUtils.strip(parsedAndUpdatedString.toString()));
            return result;
        }
 }
```

2) create a jar and upload on the edge node
3) open Hive CLI and add jar to hive classpath

```
add jar /home/ysw_test/hive-udf1.jar;
```

4) Create temporary function

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION stringParser AS 'com.ysw.hiveudf.StringParser';
```

5) use the UDF in hive query to get the desired results

```
select stringparser(state) from hivesampletable limit 5;
```

This is very useful link for learning more on Hive UDF [Good Hive UDF Link](https://dzone.com/articles/writing-custom-hive-udf-andudaf)